# Why C# threads goes idle during the execution?

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, parallel-processing, clr

I have a scheduler which runs as background thread on application start of an ASP.NET site. User can  initiate various tasks (alert emails/file generation etc) which is inserted in a db table. The scheduler will pick the tasks from database and push the items into a stack. Also scheduler has a threadpool running 10 background threads, which will pop task items from the stack and execute it.

This is running fine in one web server, but behaving strange in other web server. The threads goes idle for 6-12 seconds with no reason and do nothing even though there are items in the stack.

- Using lock() on stack object to make Push & Pop thread safe
- Tried Thread.Yield() to give yield to cpu to execute other threads, but slowing down the execution  and going idle still persists
- Tried Thread.Sleep(0) to give yield to cpu to execute other threads, but slowing down the execution and going idle still persists
- Logged entries and exit of all methods to check if something going wrong during the execution, but no luck

My questions:

1. Is execution of threads in .net in-deterministic?
2. Is it necessary to specify Thread.Yield() or Thread.Sleep(0) to give breathing time to cpu?
3. Why it is behaving differently on boxes with same configuration? Is there any machine/environment specific factors that affect the execution of thread?

> UPDATE on May.08.2013

There are two boxes in the farm, both are identical in hardware configuration, setup with same software configuration as well Windows 2008 64bit / IIS7. Both webserver has only one site each with same build. Application pools of both site runs on Framework V4.0 on integrated mode. This is a legacy code and no chance since last two years.

We tried several iterations, in all cases webserver1 executes without any issues and completes the background work quickly as it was earlier. **BUT webserver2 has significant delay and performing very poor.**

We tried extensive logging, capturing entries/exit of all methods. The scenario is like this, all threads works fine for 2 seconds and then goes idle for 6-12 seconds, again become live and execute for next 2 seconds and then goes idle again. This behavioral is consistent till the completion of the task. There is no exception, no application termination, no error in application pool/iis log.

Any idea ?

Comment: 1. Yes. 2. No. 3. You probably have a bug/race condition that only one configuration is capable of bringing out; without knowing more about the code this is hard to know for sure though.

Comment: @Servy Why the execution of thread slowing down when using Thread.Yield() or Thread.Sleep(0)?

Comment: @Servy the orginal code is complex, however i have updated the question with mock code.

Comment: Because both of those methods are telling the thread to do nothing for a period of time, with the obvious result being lower throughput.

Comment: Because you force windows task scheduler to stop executing your thread and go and do something else.

Comment: You are asking a question that only a debugger can answer reliably.  Debug + Break All, Debug + Windows + Threads.  Look at their call stacks to see what they are doing.

Comment: Is there any machine/environment specific factors that affect the execution of thread?

Comment: @eka Sure, lots.  It will determine which threads are scheduled on which cores at what times, how long they run, how fast they run, how many are able to run at the same time, how much time is spent doing productive work vs on context switches, then there are all sorts of issues with how shared memory is accessed based on caching, etc.  And that's just for starters.

Comment: @Servy from cpu/os perspective you are absolutely right, in adition to that do .NET thread management has any role in suspending threads underlying in main thread/process. say if clr want to execute other priority threads, could be clr related or webrequest or something?

Comment: @eka, does the mock code exhibit the same behavior as the real code on the trouble machine? (becoming idle for several seconds)

Comment: Nop, this code is working fine. I am having problem with real code.

Comment: @eka Is there a possibility that the running tasks are contending for a shared resource?  (perhaps one of the tasks is long-running and is holding a lock to a shared resource)

Comment: @sgorozco +1 possibilities are there

Comment: @all, Today we investigated further and identified that there is a race-condition in increment/decrement an integer variable QueueCount. We have two webservers and the same code runs without any issues, and same number of tasks are executed within 4 seconds. Whereas the same takes 2-3 minutes in other webserver most probably due to race condition on QueueCount. Why this behaviour? Is there any configuration (machine level or clr level) that affects the thread?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay guys finally we pinned the issue.

One of the cpu core of the webserver was hitting 100% and never comes back. Whereas other cores are at 0-5%.

We did a load testing for normal - moderate - heavy loads. While generating normal to moderate load the server is serving decently, properly sharing the process execution with all other cpu cores. But when we generate heavy load, things change, server struggles to distribute the load among the cores and the thread goes idle for 6-7 seconds. We assume that due to the failure of one cpu core its dealing with some fuzzy logic to distribute the process among the cores.

After further investigation we found that Windows NT Kernel is causing this problem, might be due to corruption or driver related issue.

Answer (score 0):

Your threads are repeatedly trying to grab a lock which may be causing contention. But should not be 6-12 seconds - that answer only debugger can provide.

You can use `AutoResetEvent` and wait on it in worker threads - and `Set` the event when you push item to stack.

Comment: nop, i don't think so, we logged the entries and exit of the methods and lock statement is inside the method call. the his is not even comming to the method. Also i could have used autoreset event to notify each other, if there was just two threads. In my case there multiple threads (10) watching the stack. i can't call reset to notify a particular thread

Comment: Sorry, did not get meaning of " the his is not even comming to the method".

Comment: Your debug write statements will not be printed if you use release build binaries. Use `Trace` instead. All 10 threads can wait on one AutoResetEvent. When you push one item to stack call `Set`.  One of the waiting threads will get freed and process item. There is no need to  call `Reset`

Comment: Based on some comments on the question itself and one comment by @sgorozco  - if the Mock code is working fine then it is impossible for us to figure your problem out. You have to reveal more details. One possibility why threads can freeze is Garbage collection. Check whether you are inadvertently inducing GC by creating too many objects at startup. Best solution for you is if you have $$$ then run your code through profiler. Or you can also take a hangdump of the process when you see the delay and check heapstats.

Comment: we have two webservers with same configuration, the same code and same tasks are working fine and finishes in 4 sec. Unfortunately taking too much time like 2-3 minutes in other one.

Comment: is app pool configuration same on both boxes? how many other web sites are deployed on problem machine? is this problem like works on staging but does not work in production? What other processes running on the problem machine? You should take CPU performance counters on both machines while startup - that may give you some clue.

Comment: two webserver in production, both same configuration, only one site running on ASP.NET 4.0 integrated mode. Same build on both servers. I took performance counters on both server its ranging between 10-15% CPU time with no spikes and memory consumption flat straight line (.net and system)

Comment: so, same site (your site) running on classic pipeline on one machine and integrated on other ? and you see the problem on classic configuration?

Comment: no no, application pool on both servers running on integrated mode, we compared each properties of application pool settings and iis settings, identical configuration. works on one machine but fails on other

Comment: OK - looks like there is something fundamental we are missing in this discussion. Since your system is production machine - you will probably not have VS there. You can use VS stand-alone profiler and do  a CPU sampling of the app pool process when you see the 2-3 minute delay. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb385771.aspx